# Get class name from instance Class<?>

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
public Method getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

Is there a way to get the name of the classes from `parameterTypes`?

The value of `parameterTypes` is `Class[0]@46617`

Comment: `parameterTypes` is a (variable length) array of `Class`es, not one `Class`

Comment: `parameterTypes` is an array, so it will be a `Class[]`. If you need the types of the parameters themselves you need to check those.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, I knew that :) I edited my question. How to get those?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I've edited my question to better explain my problem. Do you know how to get the name of classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are using [varargs (`...`)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs), so you will not be able to get the name of just one class, as a varargs argument is simply an array of arbitrary length. The `toString()` result you are seeing is just [Object's default `toString` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

Since you have an array, you may get the name of each `Class<?>` type individually:

```
for(Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
    parameterType.getCanonicalName();
}
```

The method [`.getCanonicalName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName()) will return a fully qualified class name including the package prefix, but there are [other methods available](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html).

It's also worth noting that in your specific example you have a `Class[0]` (an array of `Class` elements **of length zero**), so even with a for loop you won't be able to see anything if this array is not populated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized that Class[0]@46617 is just an empty array :) In the case of Class[4], I'm able to get the name

Comment: Ah yes. I'll add that to my answer in case it helps anyone else realize.